# Arduino Nano Atmega328P doesn't work on Macbook

Tags: usb, arduino-nano, mac-os

I've bought and Arduino Nano compatible on eBay:

[image]

But by the time I connect it to my Macbook Pro (OS X El Capitan 10.11.2) doesn't appear under "Tools -> Port" in Arduino IDE:

[image]

I've followed some instructions by other posts here in StackOverflow:

- [Arduino Nano no serial port for MacBook Air 2013](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/arduino-nano-no-serial-port-for-macbook-air-2013)
- [Arduino Nano with Mac OS Yosemite 10.10](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13813/arduino-nano-with-mac-os-yosemite-10-10)

But none of them worked :(

If someone could help me out with this issue I'll be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: What serial chip is on that board?

Comment: The chip is an Atmega 328P

Comment: No, I said SERIAL chip. Turn it over. That one, right there.

Comment: So sorry Majenko. CH340G is in the serial chip. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I guessed as much. Good luck with that then - that chip has real problems with Yosemite.

Comment: Sorry I can't help with it since I don't use a Mac. I just know there are often problems with Yosemite.

Comment: Actually you really helped me. Because of your question about the "serial chip" I was be able to look for a solution for that chip in Yosemite! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was be able to solve the issue.

By looking for the serial chip my board has: CH340G I found this blog post:

http://kiguino.moos.io/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

So I downloaded the signed driver for my chip and now it works :D

Driver: http://kiguino.moos.io/downloads/CH34x_Install.zip